# Specifications in the axis environment ignored

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is a similar display from another post of mine. There are only two differences.  (One of these differences is the placements of the labels for the lines.  In my post, I had the labels along the lines. Due to the comments from Gonzalo Medina, I now have the labels at the end of the lines.) The other difference is that I edited the `axis` environment to make it more concise.  I added

`x tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=south,shift=-4pt}`

to `xticklabel style=` and

`y tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,shift=-4pt}`

to `yticklabel style=`.  Why are these specifications are ignored?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    xmin=-54,xmax=90,ymin=-54,ymax=90,
    restrict y to domain=-54:90,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={15},
    extra x tick labels={15},
    xticklabel style={x tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=south,shift=-4pt}},
    extra y ticks={15},
    extra y tick labels={15},
    yticklabel style={y tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,shift=-4pt}},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]

%These commands draw the line y=x and put the label "$\ell$" 7.5pt from the right arrow tip
%in the same direction of the line.
\addplot[dashed,latex-,samples=2,domain=-54:-21,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};
\addplot[dashed,-latex,samples=2,domain=18:90,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};
\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-54:90]{x};
\node at ($(axis cs:90,90)!7.5pt!(axis cs:100,100)$) {$\ell$};

%These commands label the vertices of triangle ABC. P is the point on line segment AC at the
%base of the altitude from B.
\draw (axis cs:-30,-30) coordinate(A) node[left]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:-21,29) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:18,42) coordinate(C) node[above]{$C$};
\draw (axis cs:0,15) coordinate(P);

%These commands draw a line through B and C.
\addplot[dashed,latex-,samples=2,domain=-54:90,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};

%These commands label the vertices of triangle AB'C'. (The reflection of B across the line
%y=x is labeled B' and the reflection of C across the line y=x is labeled C'.) P' is the
%point on line segment AC' at the base of the altitude from B'.
\draw (axis cs:29,-21) coordinate(B') node[below right]{$B^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:42,18) coordinate(C') node[right]{$C^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:15,0) coordinate(P');

%These commands draw a line through B' and C'. (Its domain is expressed as the union of the
%intervals [18,29] and [42,66] because the side B'C' is dashed and the line through B' and
%C' is drawn with "loosely dash dot.")
\addplot[latex-,samples=2,loosely dash dot,domain=18:29,green]{3 * x - 108};
\addplot[-latex,samples=2,loosely dash dot,domain=42:66,green]{3 * x - 108};

\draw [fill] (54,54) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}

\draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed,blue] (B) -- (P);


\draw[dashed,green] (A) -- (B') -- (C') -- cycle;
\draw[densely dashed,green] (B') -- (P');

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please check whether your MWE is compilable.

Comment: @percusse  I just edited it.

Answer (score 3):

You are nesting identical style keys: `xticklabel style` and `x tick label style` are the abbreviations for the same key `every x tick label/.style` for compatibility reasons. Remove the inner or the outer to have the effect.

Edit: to clarify discussion in comments I add the complete MWe with some explanation:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}
% just to show only picture
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    xmin=-54,xmax=90,ymin=-54,ymax=90,
    restrict y to domain=-54:90,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={15},
    extra x tick labels={15},
% here is correct definition of xticklabel, 
% also are corrected anchor and deleted shift, it is now unnecessary
    xticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=north},
    extra y ticks={15},
    extra y tick labels={15},% here is correct definition of xticklabel, 
% here is correct definition of yticklabel, 
    yticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,xshift=+4pt},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
    ]
\addplot[dashed,latex-,samples=2,domain=-54:-21,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};
\addplot[dashed,-latex,samples=2,domain=18:90,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};
\addplot[dashed,latex-latex,samples=2,domain=-54:90]{x};
\node at ($(axis cs:90,90)!7.5pt!(axis cs:100,100)$) {$\ell$};

\draw (axis cs:-30,-30) coordinate(A) node[left]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:-21,29) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:18,42) coordinate(C) node[above]{$C$};
\draw (axis cs:0,15) coordinate(P);

\addplot[dashed,latex-,samples=2,domain=-54:90,blue]{(1/3) * x + 36};

\draw (axis cs:29,-21) coordinate(B') node[below right]{$B^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:42,18) coordinate(C') node[right]{$C^{\prime}$};
\draw (axis cs:15,0) coordinate(P');

\addplot[latex-,samples=2,loosely dash dot,domain=18:29,green]{3 * x - 108};
\addplot[-latex,samples=2,loosely dash dot,domain=42:66,green]{3 * x - 108};

\draw [fill] (54,54) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}

\draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed,blue] (B) -- (P);

\draw[dashed,green] (A) -- (B') -- (C') -- cycle;
\draw[densely dashed,green] (B') -- (P');
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding `shift`: you can decvlare shift of something by `shift=(x-direction,y-direction)` or only in x direction by `xshif=<x-distance>` or in y direction by `yshift=<y-distance`. In your case instead of `shift=-4pt for shifting in x direction should be`xshif=-4pt`or if you persist to use just shift: ˙`shift=(-4pt,0pt)`.

Comment: And correct style definition. you have errors determinimg `shift`. I supose that at `xticklabel style` is `yshift` and at `yticklabel style` is `xshift`.

Comment: @Zarko  That was careless.  If I have a `yshift` in `xticklabel style`, is it ignored?

Comment: @user74973, first use @percuse answer: instead  `yticklabel style={y tick label style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,shift=-4pt}}` use just `yticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,shift=-4pt}`, then my comment. Use of `shift` expect two parameters, not just one as you have in your MWE: instead `shift=-4pt` you should write for example `yshift=-4pt` or `shift=(0,-4pt)`.

Comment: @percusse  I did not know that issuing the same key would cancel the implementation of either of them.  I also did not know that `xticklabel style` and `x tick label style` are abbreviations for the same key.  That is of some help making my code more concise.

Comment: @percusse  I now have `every x tick label/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=south,yshift=-4pt}` and `every y tick label/.style={font=\tiny,fill=white,anchor=west,xshift=-4pt}` to label the two tick marks on the axes.  They are not shifted the same as they were in the code in my post.  Actually I had to replace `-4pt` with `4pt` to get the same display!  Why is that?

Comment: @Zarko  See my last comment to Percusse.

Comment: @user74973 That code can't compile because `shift` key needs a coordinate with braces around it. Probably you have errors in your code but TeX is in nonstopmode so you get some results.

Comment: @percusse  Are you saying that I need `xshift={-4pt}`?

Comment: @percuse, if you agree, I can add to your answer complete MWE to clarify what we discus here. Apparently some misunderstand is present ...

Comment: @Zarko  Yes.  As you can tell from my questions, I think that there is some inconsistency with `xshiftt` and `yshift`.

Comment: I will wait for while that @percuse have a time to give answer to ma proposition. If he will not give me in a reasonable time, I will write my own answer.

Comment: @Zarko You can edit anytime you want. In fact if you wish I can delete this so that we have a working MWE. No need for asking but @ user74973 you should be receiving errors. Are you trying to compile the code already? It should be obvious once you compile it.